# wxPython Enter Button Event

Tags: events, wxpython, enter

I've seen plenty of information about this topic, but not the answer to this question exactly. I have the opposite problem of most. I want to prevent the Enter button from clicking a button when the button has focus. And to do this, I don't want to simply disable the button from accepting an Enter button press, but rather I want to conditionally capture the Enter button press in a callback method. Right now, I have bound the following event to all widgets in my python program:

```
parent.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.CharInputCallback)
```

The EVT_CHAR event is actually thrown when the enter button is pressed and I'm able to get the callback in my callback method. My problem is that the enter button's functionality of virtually clicking a button still goes through, despite purposely not skipping the event (which would forward on the event). Since this is happening, and I'm sure my callback method is not forwarding the event along (I've tested this by capturing characters going to a text box) I suspect that the enter button throws an additional event that I'm not capturing. I've tried binding and capturing the additional following events to prevent the "virtual click" from the enter button:

```
parent.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.CharInputCallback)
parent.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP, self.CharInputCallback)
parent.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.CharInputCallback)
```

Yet when I press enter, the button in focus is still clicked. To summarize, is there an additional event being thrown when I press the enter button? If so, which event in particular is "virtually clicking" the button? Most forums I've found have discussed how to recognize when the enter button is pressed, but I want to recognize it and disable it's default action when a button is in focus.

Answer (score 0):

I tried binding all those events to different handlers and I also bound EVT_BUTTON. It appears that EVT_BUTTON always fires BEFORE the key and char events do. If you don't want your button to be clicked, then you'll probably have to either disable it, use a different widget (maybe one of the generic buttons) or create your own. I would also ask on the wxPython mailing list to see if they have any suggestions.

The only way to order the events in wxPython that I'm aware of is to use wx.CallAfter or wx.CallLater. I'm not sure how you'd use that in this context though.

Comment: I found that the key up event was the one that caused a button click. Or eventually led to a button click. By capturing and not skipping the key up event I was able to prevent the enter button from clicking buttons in focus. Interestingly, I was having some problems when binding all of my previously mentioned events. Currently I'm capturing the EVT_CHAR and KEY_UP events. This seems to do the trick.

Comment: Huh. Odd. I didn't notice that behavior on Windows 7. Anyway, I'm glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

The event that causes enter to click a button is the key up event. My code for my callback was messed up slightly. Capturing the key up event and not skipping it prevent the enter button from clicking a button in focus. On Windows 7 anyways.